# Use of database name in connection string

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

What is the use of mentioning the database name in connection string while opening a connection from dot net application to SQL server? Because even though we mention a database name in connection string we have to explicitly write the fully qualified name (DBName.schemaName.ProcName) while calling a stored procedure if the default DB is different for that particular user.

Comment: "even though we mention a database name ... if the default DB is different for that particular user" - not in my experience. If you name a database in the connection string, you shouldn't need to also use the database name to call a stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to database from a .NET application is different from accessing a table of different database.

> use of mentioning the database name in connection string

so for instance you can use connection string below to connect to **myDB** at **MyServer**

Data Source=**MyServer**;Initial Catalog=**myDB**;Integrated Security=True

if you will not specify at least these information how your .NET application can connect to a stored procedure (**MyProcInMyDB**) located in **myDB**.

Now for part you asked

> though we mention a database name while calling a stored procedure if
>   the default DB is different for that particular user

this is not a normal case to access stored procedure of another database using same connection string if it is a very special case (not likely) then you will do it for calling one or two stored procedures. But if it is required quite often within your application then you should create a separate connection string. Using same connection string and calling like

```
command.CommandText = "myDB2.dbo.getList"
```

can result is difficult maintenance and flexibility

Comment: My question was, if I mention MyDB in connection string for user MyUser and try executing a stored procedure by mentioning dbo.MyProcName, it will give error if the MyUser default DB is other than MyDB. Then what is the use eof mentioning DB name in connection string?

Comment: That should be because of security permissions for that user; might be user has no access permission for myDB or proc execution but this error should not be because of  a different default DB. Mostly "master" is default db but still we can connect to different databases

Comment: Yes, master was the default DB. But the error was "could not find stored procedure MyProcName". MyUser had execute access on MyProcName and the error got resolved when I changed the default DB for MyUser to MyDB from master. Again my question is what is the use of DBName in connection string if it doesn't open connection to mentioned DB?